# Temporarily restrict certain resources from build inclusion in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

Is there a way to temporarily restrict which resources are included in the build of an iPhone app (via Xcode)?

I am testing a use case in my app and want to minimize the installation time on my device.  I would like to do this by reducing the resources to only those needed by this use case... i.e. there are over 70MB of .wav and .png files that I do not need to copy over.

I am looking for something more elegant than moving the out of the project into a separate directory on the file system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please mark the answer below as correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this: duplicate your target in XCode (on the left-hand side of the XCode project window, open "Targets", click on your application target, then choose "duplicate" from the Edit menu).

In the duplicated target, go into the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase and remove the files you don't want. Switch your "Active Target" (using the menu at the top of the project window) and build.